# How to use WeakRef in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, weak-references

I want to use WeakRef in Typescript. I tried using the last version available at the moment (4.1.5).
I have a compilation error:

```
const toIdString = (o: Object): string =>
  o.constructor.name + JSON.stringify(o);

export class MemoCache {
  static handle<T>(o: T): T {
    const id = toIdString(o);
    const cached = MemoCache.map.get(id);
    if (cached) {
      return cached.deref() as T;
    }
    MemoCache.map.set(id, new WeakRef(o));
    return o;
  }

  static map = new Map<string, WeakRef>();
}
```

I have compilation errors.

```
src/Memoizer.ts:11:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakRef'.

11     MemoCache.map.set(id, new WeakRef(o));
                                 ~~~~~~~

src/Memoizer.ts:15:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakRef'.

15   static map = new Map<string, WeakRef>();
                                  ~~~~~~~
```

However, this is ECMAScript 2021. Chrome 88 seems to understand it.
I have node 15.8.0 (the last one)
Do you have any idea how to make Typescript understand WeakRef ?

Comment: Use ESNext, maybe? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/esnext.weakref.d.ts

Comment: Indeed: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDhAvBAdiA7hAsvAPAZzACcBLFAcwBoIB1EGAawCUQAzXAeQCMArEAYzAA+IQAoAlAG4gA

Comment: Yes guys ! Thank you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the 18 Feb 2021, in order to use `WeakRef` in Typsecript, you need to have and configure `tsconfig.json` by adding `ESNext` to the `lib` property.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
// ...
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
// ...
  },
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A more nuanced options is to explicitly include `ES2021.WeakRef` in the `tsconfig.json` `lib`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ES2020", "ES2021.WeakRef"],
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

Note:

- `ES2020` is the lib setting for Node 14.
- `ES2021` is the lib setting for Node 16.
- `ES2022` is the lib setting for Node 18.

See: [tsconfig/bases: Hosts TSConfigs to extend in a TypeScript app, tuned to a particular runtime environment](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases)